# Is dynamically Adding Meta Tag Using PHP is SEO friendly

Tags: php, seo

I have a doubt that adding dynamically the meta tags using server script can minimize scope of SEO friendly can anyone tell it good or not to do that ?

**//Header1.php**

```
<html class="no-js" lang=""> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title><?php echo $title ;?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $title ;?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
</html>
```

**//home.php**

```
<?php
    $title="Portfolio";
    include ('../assets/includes/header1.php');
?>
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio text-center">
    <div class="portfolio-bottom">
        <div class="section-padding">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php
    include ('../assets/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Whether such meta tags are static or are created in a dynamic manner is irrelevant, since a client cannot tell the difference. However most (if not all) of today's web search robots ignore meta tags completely. So you can simply leave them away.

Comment: So basically you are saying , I can keep like the way it is now

Comment: Certainly you can, does not hurt. Or you simply remove those meta tags.

Comment: Thanks , sir I will do that, One more thing can you provide me with links , where i can use .htaccess file to hide the folder like abc/views/index.php to abc/index.php I was going through your page found your works are helpful so kindly help

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question, so that all contributors here can take a look at it and help. Also browsing through existing answers will probably help you, check the questions mentioned under "Related" on the right hand side.

Comment: @arkascha You are quite wrong! Google is certainly not ignoring all meta tags. The [description] type used in the question is what Google shows in the result list and should be quite important for most web sites. Putting the title there is not very efficient, though. The [keywords] type is however something rarely used for indexing nowadays.

Comment: @jitheman Sir i was just showing an example , I will use different variable where I will put requirements Of content, The main question was is this process hinders SEO ?